# Should my Docker base image variants match my underlying host OS?

Tags: linux, docker, debian

For example, I have a server running Ubuntu 16.x that hosts a set of Docker containers that are running `FROM node:x.x.x-stretch`.  The `stretch` variant is built off of Debian Jessie (the same version Ubuntu 16.x is built off of).

Is there any reason I *shouldn't* be using the latest Node image (node:x.x.x-buster), where `-buster` is built off of Debian 10?

From what I understand, this means that my node image would be more up-to-date / supported longer at the small cost of having less shared with the underlying host OS.  Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why people don't automatically update to the latest version, is due to package dependencies. It's difficult to keep track of what packages are dependent on what version of node, let alone what version of other packages.

Comment: I understand why I wouldn't use `node:latest`, but what I'm trying to figure out is if there's any particular reason to use `-stretch` containers on a Debian 9 host OS or if it doesn't really matter if it's a `-buster` (Debian 10) container on a Debian 9 host system.